# Why does this PHP script insert the data twice?

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem is solved, made a dumb error, included a print and screen version...**

---

This script is inserting the data twice, I tried some things and I'm not getting it to work. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    include("config.inc.php");
$continue = '';
$sessiontekst = md5(date("d-m-Y"));
$sessionname = "Secure";
if(!isset($_SESSION[$sessionname]) or $_SESSION[$sessionname] != $sessiontekst)
{
$continue = 'Je bent niet ingelogd';
}
if($continue == '') {
```

Above is the section that checks the login. Down here is the script that processes the data from the form

```
    // startup
    $result_final = "";
    $counter = 0;

    // Arrays
    $opmerking = $_POST['opmerkingen'];
    $datum = $_POST['datum'];
    $docent = $_POST['docent'];
    $vak = $_POST['vak'];
    $stroming = $_POST['stroming'];
    $lokaal = $_POST['lokaal'];
    $tijd = $_POST['tijd'];


    while ($counter < count($datum))
    {
    if ($datum[$counter] == '')
    { echo 'Geen datum ingevoerd<br>';}
    elseif ($tijd[$counter] == '')
    { echo 'Geen tijd ingevoerd<br>';}
    else {
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO toetsrooster (`docent`, `vak`, `lokaal`, `datum`, `tijd`,  `richting`, `opmerkingen`) VALUES ('".addslashes($docent[$counter])."', '".addslashes($vak[$counter])."', '".addslashes($lokaal[$counter])."', '".addslashes($datum[$counter])."', '".addslashes($tijd[$counter])."',  '".addslashes($stroming[$counter])."', '".addslashes($opmerking[$counter])."')" );
$result_final .= "Toets ".($counter+1)." toegevoegd<br />";
    }
    $counter++;
    mysql_error();
    }
```

The part that shows the output of the script, it says that it added the data once, but it ads the data twice.

```
    // Print Result
echo <<<__HTML_END

<html>
<head>
    <title>Toetsen toegevoegd</title>
</head>
<body>
    $result_final
</body>
</html>

__HTML_END;
}
```

And again a bit for the check of the login

```
else {
    echo $continue;
}
?>
```

The code of the form:

```
<?
$continue = '';
$sessiontekst = md5(date("d-m-Y"));
$sessionname = "Secure";
if(!isset($_SESSION[$sessionname]) or $_SESSION[$sessionname] != $sessiontekst)
{
$continue = 'Je bent niet ingelogd';
}
if($continue == '') {
include("config.inc.php");
include("lijstenbouwer.inc.php");
//Standaard aantal
$velden = 6;
$veldenoutput = "";
$counter = 1;
//Kijken of er een URL variabele is voor ?p=velden
if( $_GET['velden'] )
    $velden = (int)($_GET['velden']);
//Velden bouwen
while( $counter <= $velden )
    {
$veldenoutput .=
<<<__HTML_END
<tr>
<td>
<select name='stroming[]'>
            $stroming
        </select></td><td><select name='vak[]'>
            $vak
        </select></td><td>
        <select name='docent[]'>
            $docent
        </select></td><td><select name='lokaal[]'>
            $lokaal
        </select></td><td>

    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="$counter" name="datum[]" placeholder="Klik op de kalender"></td><td><input type="text" name="tijd[]" placeholder="12:00 - 13:00"></td><td><input type="text" name="opmerkingen[]" placeholder="Opmerkingen"></td>
</tr>
        <script>
    $('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            dayNames : ['Zondag', 'Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Zo', 'Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za'],
            firstDay: 1,
            monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December']
            });
});
    </script>
__HTML_END;
$counter++;
    }
//Output
echo <<<__HTML_END

<table width="100%">
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='index.php?p=verwerking/toetoevoegen' method='post' name='toevoegen'>
<tr>
<td>Stroming</td><td>Vak</td><td>Docent</td><td>Lokaal</td><td>Datum</td><td>Tijd</td><td>Opmerkingen</td>
</tr>
$veldenoutput
</table><input class="verzenden" name="verzenden" type="submit" value="Verzend"></form>
__HTML_END;
}
else {
    echo $continue;
}
?>
```

When this data is entered: [The data](https://skitch.com/nubels/88yjn/toetsrooster-o-matic%22), the var_dump is:

```
array(8) { ["stroming"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["vak"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["docent"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["lokaal"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["datum"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "01-03-2012" [1]=> string(10) "02-03-2012" } ["tijd"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Time 1" [1]=> string(6) "Time 2" } ["opmerkingen"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "Comment 1" [1]=> string(9) "Comment 2" } ["verzenden"]=> string(7) "Verzend" }
```

Comment: What does `$datum` contain? Right now if it contains one element, your while loop will execute twice.

Comment: Your mysql_query() call is within the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide the value of `$_POST['datum']` for an example where your query gets executed twice? The obvious answer is that the loop's body of `while ($counter < count($datum))` is executed twice. That is the case if `count($datum) > 1`.

You should also escape with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of `addslashes`.

I ran this to test your code locally. You can try if the error occurs if you just execute this shortened version, if you want.

```
<?php

$result_final = "";
$counter = 0;

$opmerking = array('Comment 1', 'Comment 2');
$datum =  array('01-03-2012', '02-03-2012');
$docent =  array('1', '1');
$vak =  array('1', '1');
$stroming =  array('1', '1');
$lokaal =  array('1', '1');
$tijd =  array('Time 1', 'Time 2');

while ($counter < count($datum))
{
    if ($datum[$counter] == '')
    {
        echo 'Geen datum ingevoerd<br>';
    }
    elseif ($tijd[$counter] == '')
    {
        echo 'Geen tijd ingevoerd<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump( "INSERT INTO toetsrooster (`docent`, `vak`, `lokaal`, `datum`, `tijd`,  `richting`, `opmerkingen`) VALUES ('".addslashes($docent[$counter])."', '".addslashes($vak[$counter])."', '".addslashes($lokaal[$counter])."', '".addslashes($datum[$counter])."', '".addslashes($tijd[$counter])."',  '".addslashes($stroming[$counter])."', '".addslashes($opmerking[$counter])."')" );
        $result_final .= "Toets ".($counter+1)." toegevoegd<br />";
    }
    $counter++;
    mysql_error();
}

echo <<<__HTML_END

<html>
<head>
    <title>Toetsen toegevoegd</title>
</head>
<body>
    $result_final
</body>
</html>

__HTML_END;

?>
```

Comment: $_POST['datum'] is an array with dates. The dates are formatted like this: 04-03-2012

Comment: So there is your answer. If `$_POST['datum']` is an array with more than one value, `count($datum)` will be `> 1` and your `while`-loop will be executed more than once.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want the data only inserted once, or the output to say that two rows got inserted? I did a simple test with your code and got `'Toets 1 toegevoegd<br />Toets 2 toegevoegd<br />'` for `$result_final` after inserting two rows.

Comment: The problem is that each data in the form is inserted in the database twice but it says just like above that it did it's work twice. So if you submit two things in the form, there are four rows in the database with each thing twice. If I enter this: [link](https://skitch.com/nubels/88yjn/toetsrooster-o-matic"), this happens: [link](http://skit.ch/njnq)

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the form's markup and/or a `var_dump($_POST);` when submitting the form? The problem seems to be the form. I expect $_POST to already contain the 4 rows of data. I don't see any problems with the code you provided so far.

Comment: Updated the post with the code of the form and the var_dump output.

Comment: I don't see any problem so far. Your $_POST['datum'] contains two values, therefore two inserts are done. My local test shows two ?`mysql_query`-calls using the data from your `var_dump`.

Comment: I would now try to narrow the error down by for instance counting the number of rows in your database inside the loop to see if only one row gets inserted and when.

Comment: I will try to do some local tests too... Really strange this.

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows()` outputs 1 for each time.

Comment: Do you by any chance call the script twice? Is there any header("Location: xyz") in your code? Was the table empty before you executed the script? You could `mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE toetsrooster");` right before your `while`-loop to check that.

Comment: Table is empty and there are no headers. Script does the same thing local.

Comment: Suddenly remembered that the page is rendered twice, one print version and a screen version. I feel so dumb right now.